# WPF interaction command refer to local static resource for converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I wish to create a "reusable" control item which has a behaviour attribute. As described [in this blog](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/)

For the data binding the data has to be converted. The problem is; as `StaticResource` it can only see the top level dictionary (`app`), and dynamic resources don't work ("can only be used with a dependency property").

The simple (working) xaml (window):

```
<Window x:Class="testit.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="blah" Fill="Yellow" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="100">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" >
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseEnterCommand}">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                            <Binding Path="Name"
                                     Converter="{StaticResource SelectionConverter}"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Rectangle}" />
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                    </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock x:Name="namefield" Text="{Binding Data}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

app:

```
<Application x:Class="testit.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testit"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:SelectionConverter x:Key="SelectionConverter" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And finally the viewmodel:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace testit
{
    class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _data;
        private readonly DelegateCommand<string> _mouseEnterCommand = null;

        public ViewModel() {
            _data = "hello ";
            _mouseEnterCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(
                (s) => {
                    var a = s ?? "world ";
                    Data += s;
                    return;
                });
        }

        public DelegateCommand<string> MouseEnterCommand => _mouseEnterCommand;

        public string Data {
            get { return _data; }
            set {
                if (value == _data) return;
                _data = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Data");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public class SelectionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            if (value == null) return "";
            char[] charArray = ((string)value).ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            return new string(charArray);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Now as said, this "works". However it doesn't do what I wish: it clutters the top level resource dictionary. I wish to remove the resource from app. and put it under the Grid. (Or whatever panel I use).

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <local:SelectionConverter x:Key="SelectionConverter" />
</Grid.Resources>
```

---

EDIT:If I add above line to the grid inside the window the following error is thrown on compilation (the line and position refer to the `Converter="{StaticResource SelectionConverter}"`)

> "'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an
>   exception.' Line number '13' and line position '38'."

With the inner exception:

> Cannot find resource named 'SelectionConverter'. Resource names are
>   case sensitive.

For clarity, this is the modified window.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="testit.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="blah" Fill="Yellow" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="100">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" >
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseEnterCommand}">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                            <Binding Path="Name"
                                     Converter="{StaticResource SelectionConverter}"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Rectangle}" />
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                    </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock x:Name="namefield" Text="{Binding Data}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:SelectionConverter x:Key="SelectionConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I would think that should work, if the Grid where it’s defined is a parent of the control where it’s used

Comment: @EdPlunkett we must be misundestanding each other, as it most certainly doesn't work.

Comment: Try putting `Grid.Resources` at the top of the Grid, not the bottom. `StaticResource` resolves the resource very early in the parsing process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StaticResource` markup extension resolves the resource immediately, when `ProvideValue` is called:

> [Lookup behavior for that resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/staticresource-markup-extension) is analogous to load-time lookup, which will look for **resources that were previously loaded** from the markup of the current XAML page

If `Grid.Resources` is defined *after* the content of the `Grid`, those resources haven't been "previously loaded" when the content of the `Grid` is parsed.

So put the resources at the top of the grid, so anything in there is defined before you use it:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:SelectionConverter x:Key="SelectionConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Rectangle x:Name="blah" Fill="Yellow" Stroke="Black" Width="100" Height="100">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" >
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseEnterCommand}">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        <Binding Path="Name"
                                 Converter="{StaticResource SelectionConverter}"
                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Rectangle}" />
                    </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                </i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
    <TextBlock x:Name="namefield" Text="{Binding Data}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

If you were able to use `DynamicResource`, you'd be fine, but of course you can't, for reasons you discovered.